# Added domain to webflow without verification or adding any details to the host and now the website is gone

Tags: dns, host, webflow

We are working on a new website, but are at the very beginning of the projects. I'm not a developer and I do not really understand what's happening so I just need some information. I'd be really thankful if someone could explain what happened and why.

We will need to add the domain to Webflow, but not now. I wanted to ask the senior developer of a few details and if he has access to the platform where we have our domain.

I went to Webflow and added a domain manually by entering the URL. I wanted to create a screenshot of the details that shows up afterwards to send these to the senior developer.

Now the website is gone.

Why is it? Can it be even possible? I basically did not do anything except for typing in the URL.